How to fit random slope hierarchical model as SEM with OpenMx in R?
I've been exploring the OpenMx Package in R in hopes to fit multilevel path analysis and I can't figure out how to add random slope.
This is the model I am trying to fit:
$$
Y_{ij} = \beta_{0j} + \beta_{1j} X_{ij} + e_{ij}
$$
$$
\beta_{0j} = \gamma_{00} + U_{0j}
$$
$$
\beta_{1j} = \gamma_{10} + U_{1j}
$$
Here is some code to simulate multilevel data
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(OpenMx)

J <- 100 #number of clusters 
n_j <- 30#number of observations 

gamma_00 <- 5
gamma_10 <- 3
mu_x <- 4


sim.dat <- data.frame(J_ID = 1:J) |> 
  mutate(U_0j = rnorm(J, mean = 0 , sd = 1),
         U_1j = rnorm(J, mean = 0, sd = 1),
         gamma_00 = gamma_00,
         gamma_10 = gamma_10,
         n_j = n_j) |> 
  rowwise() |> 
  mutate(X = list(rnorm(n_j, mu_x, sd = 1)),
         R = list(rnorm(n_j, 0, sd = 1))) |> 
  unnest(cols = c(X, R)) |> 
  mutate(Y = gamma_00 + U_0j + (gamma_10 + U_1j) * X + R)


sim.dat.obs <- sim.dat|> 
  select(J_ID, X, Y) |> 
  mutate(J_ID = as.factor(J_ID))

Here is my code using Openmx. I am not sure how to connect the latent variable slope in the level 2 to the level 1 observed variables.
manifest_names <- sim.dat|> 
  select(Y, x) |> 
  names()
clusterID <- data.frame(cluster_ID = 1:J)


level2 <- mxModel(model = "level 2", type = "RAM",
                      latentVars = c("intercept", "slope"),
                      mxData(clusterID, 
                             type = "raw",
                             primaryKey = "cluster_ID"),
                      mxPath(from =c("intercept", "slope"), #Variances & covariances
                             arrows = 2, values = 2,
                             connect = "unique.pairs"))

level1 <- mxModel(model = "level 1", type = "RAM",
                      level2,
                      manifestVars = manifest_names,
                      mxData(sim.dat,
                             type = "raw"),
                      mxPath(from = "X", to = "Y",
                             arrow = 1, values = 1),
                      mxPath(from = "level 2.intercept", to = "Y", #Random intercept
                         arrow = 1, value = 1, free = FALSE,
                         joinKey = "cluster_ID"), #What mxPath goes for random slope?
                      mxPath(from = "one", to = manifest_names,
                             arrow = 1, value = 1),
                      mxPath(from = c("X", "Y"), #variance
                             arrow = 2, value = 2,
                             connect = "single"))

model_fit <- mxRun(level1)

I want to be able to recover parameters from the simulated data.

Following guidence from (Paras & Neale, 2005) this is what the path diagram could look like:

I use math notation to align with HLM instead of SEM.
Specify the path related to the $j$ level here is only the variance and covariance of random intercept and random slope.
J_obs <- sim.dat.obs |> 
  select(J_ID) |> 
  distinct()

J_cluster_name <- "J_ID"

J_latent <- c("U_0", "U_1")

J_data <- mxData(J_obs, type = "raw",
                 primaryKey = J_cluster_name)

J_var <- mxPath(from = J_latent,
                arrows = 2, values = 1,
                connect = "single",
                labels = c("tau0", "tau1"))
J_cov <- mxPath(from = J_latent,
                arrows = 2, values = 0,
                connect = "unique.bivariate",
                labels = "tau01")

J_model <- mxModel("Level_J", type = "RAM",
                   latentVars = J_latent,
                   J_data,
                   J_var,
                   J_cov)

Here for the level $i$ we specify all the fixed effect paths and variances for the manifest variable. Note for cross level path need the joinkey argument to join let OpenMx how to level's interact with each other. Also for the $U_0$ and $U_1$ how the variables interact with $Y$ is though the fixed values of 1 and the values of $X$ in the data. This is referred to as definition variables. The labels = c("data.X") tells Openmx to use the data as the value of the path.
## I level (Student) --------
I_obs <- mxData(sim.dat.obs, type = "raw")

I_manifest <- c("X", "Y")


I_means <- mxPath(from = "one",
                  to = c("X"),
                  labels = c("mu_x"),
                  value = 1)
I_var <- mxPath(from = c("X", "Y"),
                labels = c("sigma_x", "sigma_r"),
                arrow = 2,
                value = 1)



I_fixed <- mxPath(from = c("one","X"),
                    to = "Y",
                    value = 1,
                    labels = c("gamma_00", "gamma_10"))

I_randomslope <- mxPath(from = c("Level_J.U_1"),
                          to = c("Y"),
                          labels = c("data.X"),
                          free = FALSE,
                          joinKey = J_cluster_name)

I_randomint <- mxPath(from = c("Level_J.U_0"),
                        to = c("Y"),
                        value = 1,
                        free = FALSE,
                        joinKey = J_cluster_name)

I_model<- mxModel("Level_I", type = "RAM",
                  manifestVars = I_manifest,
                  J_model,
                  I_obs,
                  I_means,
                  I_var,
                  I_fixed,
                  I_randomslope,
                  I_randomint)
I.fit <- mxRun(I_model)

summary(I.fit)
#> Summary of Level_I 
#>  
#> free parameters:
#>       name    matrix row col  Estimate  Std.Error A
#> 1 gamma_10         A   Y   X 3.0152008 0.09842618  
#> 2  sigma_x         S   X   X 1.0069889 0.02599997  
#> 3  sigma_r         S   Y   Y 0.9965501 0.02663798  
#> 4     mu_x         M   1   X 3.9685960 0.01832109  
#> 5 gamma_00         M   1   Y 4.8246375 0.12786752  
#> 6     tau0 Level_J.S U_0 U_0 1.0403988 0.23341716 !
#> 7    tau01 Level_J.S U_0 U_1 0.1493937 0.12591683  
#> 8     tau1 Level_J.S U_1 U_1 0.9331094 0.13694490  
#> 
#> Model Statistics: 
#>                |  Parameters  |  Degrees of Freedom  |  Fit (-2lnL units)
#>        Model:              8                   5992              17758.93
#>    Saturated:             NA                     NA                    NA
#> Independence:             NA                     NA                    NA
#> Number of observations/statistics: 3100/6000
#> 
#> Information Criteria: 
#>       |  df Penalty  |  Parameters Penalty  |  Sample-Size Adjusted
#> AIC:       5774.934               17774.93                 17774.98
#> BIC:     -30411.697               17823.25                 17797.83
#> CFI: NA 
#> TLI: 1   (also known as NNFI) 
#> RMSEA:  0  [95% CI (NA, NA)]
#> Prob(RMSEA <= 0.05): NA
#> To get additional fit indices, see help(mxRefModels)
#> timestamp: 2024-05-04 12:11:58 
#> Wall clock time: 16.51345 secs 
#> optimizer:  SLSQP 
#> OpenMx version number: 2.21.8 
#> Need help?  See help(mxSummary)

References
Mehta, P. D., & Neale, M. C. (2005). People are variables too: multilevel structural equations modeling. Psychological methods, 10(3), 259.
